# How to get Ultraedit regex search to work in C/C++ code

Tags: c, regex

I am having a tough time getting an Ultraedit regex to work in C/C++ code. I am aware of adding additional `/` for `/w` but still it does not work.

```
#include<regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int reti;
    regex_t regex;
    reti = regcomp(&regex, "^\w+\.c", 0);

    if(!reti)
    {
        printf("compile success\n");
    }

    reti = regexec(&regex, "test.c", 0, NULL, 0);
    if(!reti)
    {
        printf("match\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("mis match\n");
    }

}
```

The regular expression above works properly on Ultraedit but why does it not work if put in C code as shown here?

I expect "match" to be printed out but when I run the above code, I get:

> compile success
>   mis match

Comment: Double the escape ``\`` symbol.

Comment: Adding double escape like shown does not help reti = regcomp(&regex, "^\\w+\.c", 0);

Comment: You are either writing code in C or in C++. There is no C/C++ language. Pick one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslash one more time otherwise, it would be readed as an escape sequence.

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "^\\w+\\.c", 0);
```

And also i think you're trying to match all the file names with the extension `.c`, in that case, you must use end of the line anchor.

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "^\\w+\\.c$", 0);
```

Or

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "^[[:alnum:]_]+\\.c$", 0);
```

Comment: I changed as suggested reti = regcomp(&regex, "^\\w+\\.c$", 0); ,Even this does not help my compiler version is as follows gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: try `regcomp(&regex, "(?m)^\\w+\\.c$", 0);`

Comment: reti = regcomp(&regex, "(?m)^\\w+\\.c$", 0); does not work either .But I am thinking except a double escape there should not be any thing more to it .

Comment: reti = regcomp(&regex, "^[[:alnum:]_]+\\.c$", 0);  Did not work

Comment: I guess you need `REG_EXTENDED` flag to make `$` work with C regex.

Comment: Thanks stribizhev ,REG_EXTENDED works !! any idea how to use similar option in c++11 ?will   std::regex::egrep work?

Comment: similar implementation in c++11        const std::regex re("^\\w+\\.c",std::regex::extended);
        std::smatch match;
        std::string str  ("test.c");
        if(std::regex_match(str, match,re) && match.size()>1)
        {
                printf("match\n");
        }
        else
        {

                printf("mis match\n");
        } gives "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error
Aborted (core dumped)"
what is that missing in the above code

Comment: const std::regex re("^(\\w)+\\.c");
        std::smatch match;
        std::string str  ("test.c");
        if(std::regex_match(str, match,re) && match.size()>1)
worked but why do we need additional () braces for \\w is not understood

Comment: `()` called capturing group and it won't be needed here. Try changing ` match.size()>1` to ` match.size()>=1` will work, i think.